# Hilt Dagger 2, Create instance of any object and injecting to a class

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger-hilt

I am converting my existing application to MVVM architecture, I use `hilt dagger 2` for dependency injection. In my previous code I use single thread `Executor` to execute all tasks. Now in the Dependency Injection main `Module` I would like to create an instance of Executor and then inject it in all classes. Can someone check my approach if it's good.

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class AppModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun getAppDb(context: Application) : AppDatabase {
        return AppDatabase.getInstance(context)
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun getDao(appDb: AppDatabase) : StoragesDao {
        return appDb.storagesDao()
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun getExecutor() : Executor {
        return Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    }
}
```

**StorageRepository** Class where I `inject` executor instance

```
class StorageRepository @Inject constructor(
    @ApplicationContext val context: Context,
    private val storageDao: StoragesDao,
    private val executor: Executor
    ) {

  //  private val executor: Executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()

    fun insertStorage(storagesEntity: StoragesEntity, listener: OnApiUpdateListener?) {
        executor.execute {
            storageDao.insertAll(storagesEntity)
            if (ApiUtils.isNetworkAvailable(context)) {
                post_Storage(storagesEntity, listener)
            } else {
                listener?.eventUpdate(context.getString(R.string.failure))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This would be better suited for Code Review Stack Exchange.

Comment: Ask it on Code review site https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

It’s fine, although I do have few notes.

I would put the database into `LocalPersistanceModule` so I won't spam the App module with these dependencies. There will be more, like shared prefs. This will be especially useful if you are going to spam it with `providesDao` methods for every DAO.

I don't declare Provides DAO methods. When I declare something which wants DAOs, I will use the `AppDatabase` in the provide method to fetch required DAOs, and will pass them to the object.

The `@Singleton` for your provides methods adds overhead for both build and runtime.

I don't like the `Context` dependency in the repository at all. It is data layer; it doesn't care about a context and your localized strings.